# How to Read HD when only booting to Bios with dual-boot Windows 10 and 15.10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Brand new Asus Zenbook UX305FA, came with Win 8 installed--upgraded to Win8.1, then to Win 10 prelim; dual boot with Ubuntu 15.10;

I've had no problems with this machine as setup for the past 2 weeks I've owned it, until this afternoon. In the airport I was using the machine in Windows to write some documents, I fly home, open it up, reboot it and bam--it ONLY boots into the BIOS.

I've read at least 100 articles on the net about disabling UEFI and fast boot mode and security and all this crap--also went ahead and made a Super Grub2 Disk repair USB disk and tried that, to no avail--just says it won't boot anything because it's invalid.

- I cannot read `/dev/sda` (my only SSD on the machine) from linux.
- I can however read `(hd0,1)` from Super Grub2 and see the `/boot/grub/` folder and the files, all EFI.

MBR is likely screwed, no idea why the hell this happened... any suggestions to recover my data or is this toast?

[paste does not exist]

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX305FA
Ubuntu: 15.10
Dual-boot: Windows 10

Comment: Could you reset the partition table (use gdisk or some other tool) on sda to what you had?   Maybe all you lost was the partition table.

Comment: Have you found any answer to your problem? Please, consider to provide your own answer or accept current answer if yes.

Comment: Please, provide us your paste again because it does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The main errors from your boot repair are:

```
Invalid MBR Signature found.
ERROR: asr: reading /dev/sda[Input/output error]
```

So it looks like your SSD is broken.  HDDs die a horrible death like cancer: slowly they get worse and worse, until they finally die whereas SSDs die a quick and painful death like a heart attack: they just die suddenly.

You have just one (very small) chance that the SSD got loose from its bay while you were flying: open up the HDD bay, remove the SSD, re-insert it and try again.  If that doesn't help, return the laptop to the store and get it repaired under warranty.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Ended up exchanging the laptop for a new one... what was odd is that you could read the disk information just couldn't access the data, which leads me to believe that the SSD did not come unplugged or similar. In any case, I've had the new laptop for 3 days and it's working fine so far... if this one dies, I'm getting my money back and buying an old fashioned magnetic HDD.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user424401: please don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask